# Can I force angular to give error if a component doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have a template in a component that references non-existant components, angular 1.6 seems perfectly happy to render it as nothing at all. For example I have a route currently that looks like:

```
when('/something',{
    title: 'Something',
    template: "<mycomponent></mycomponent>",
})
```

If I forget to register `mycomponent` on my application, this route renders nothing. Is there some mode I can use in angular that will cause a harder error in a case like that? Or at least print something to the console when it occurs?

To be perfectly clear, I have this issue with both top level components referenced by the router, as well as other child components that those reference recursively.

Comment: I have wasted so many hours of debugging because of this.  I'd really like to know as well.  I wish that it would trigger with the `strict-di` setting.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no option for that. By the way "non rendered" components are a benefit IMO, because you could override this slot later.

A short example:

```
when('/something',{
    title: 'Something',
    template: "<slot><mycomponent></mycomponent></slot>",
})
```

assume you want to override the ui-part of mycomponent, just define a component for "slot"

Comment: While that does seem potentially convenient, my current use case is that I just converted a pretty big app to using webpack and explicit imports and a different style, and now I gotta track down components I didn't quite port over correctly.

Comment: Mh maybe you could grep and compare these results with your registered components

Answer (score 0):

There was a routeProvider.otherwise before. Not sure if it’s still supported. I’m on a phone so limited. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: This is not about catch-all routes. That works fine. This is the case where it matches the route, but the template itself has undefined contents.

Comment: @captncraig there is a wildcard there too. Again, can’t help right now but it’s something like (path*). Let me know if this doesn’t hell and i’ll dig deeper later when I have time

Answer (score 0):

UI Router supports [components for routes](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/route-to-component), this means that it is capable of triggering an error if a component doesn't exist.

AngularJS currently doesn't offer component router. This means that route `template` is compiled as any other template with `$compile`, and unknown selectors are just ignored.

It is possible to patch ngRoute `ngView` directive to additionally check if a route that is expected to route to a component actually has it compiled.

```
// the whole list can be retrieved from commonly available sources
var htmlTags = ['p', 'div', ...];

app.directive('ngView', function () {
  return function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
    if (!DEBUG_MODE)
      return;

    if ($element.children().length !== 1)
      return;

    var routeComponent = angular.element($element.children()[0]);
    var routeComponentTagName = routeComponent.prop('tagName').toLowerCase();

    if (htmlTags.indexOf(routeComponentTagName) >= 0)
      return;

    var routeComponentName = $attrs.$normalize(routeComponentTagName);

    if (!routeComponent.controller(routeComponentName)) {
      console.warn(routeComponentTagName + ' element is non-standard yet not a component');
    }
  }
});
```

AngularJS already has [`$normalize()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$compile.directive.Attributes#$normalize) which is primarily intended for attributes and strips some specific prefixes, but as long as the components names don't have `x` or `data` prefix, it can work as generic kebab to camel case transformer.

There may be other ways to detect if a component was compiled on child element. The code above will trigger false negative if there already is parent `routeComponentName` component, because `controller()` travels up the hierarchy.

And the proper way to handle this problem is to provide test coverage for the application. Router-related cases should likely be handled in integration or e2e tests.